# Rails validations failing due to other side of association not being set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

### Problem

```
class Match
  has_many :items
end

class Item
  belongs_to :match
  validates :match, presence: true
end

class ItemBuilder
  def self.build
    5.times.map { |_| Item.new }
  end
end

class MatchBuilder
  def self.build
    Match.new(items: ItemBuilder.build)
  end
end

match = MatchBuilder.build
match.save # Validation fails because Item#match isn't set!
```

It seems to me that rails should set the `Item#match` association when assigning `Match#items`, but this is not the case.

In reality, the `ItemBuilder` builds Items from information from an API. I'd prefer it not to have knowledge of where those Items are going to be put, so I can't pass the match into `ItemBuilder`.

I'd also prefer to not have the `Matchbuilder` aware of the internals of the Items returned from `ItemBuilder`, so I can't do

```
class MatchBuilder
  def self.build
    items = ItemBuilder.build
    match = Match.new(items: items)
    items.each do |item|
      item.match = match
    end
  end
end
```

Is there any way of getting around this, without explicitly setting `Item#match`?

### Possible Solutions

- Remove the validation, and leave the database to do the not null validation
- Assign `Item#match` in a before_validation filter

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this:

```
match = Match.new
5.times { match.items.build }
match.save
```

Not sure if `autosave: true` is needed for items association in this case.

Comment: This means the object that builds the Items has to know about the Match. This is what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: In your code example, you have the three lines there.  Are they supposed to be happening in different "objects" then?  You don't say that.  I think you need to add more info to your question as it seems to be more complicated than it appears (i agree with @Magnuss's solution FWIW)

Comment: I added more details to my question.

Comment: Also, this doesn't assign the match to the items unless the match is persisted before calling build.